# Who is the target of the prohibition of graphical representations of Allah and Muhamad?

Tags: quran, allah, prophet-muhammad, image, obligation

Who is the prohibition addressed to?

Believers, or everyone? In other words, is it a requirement of faith where Muslims are themselves banned from the action, or whether they should also actively seek the picture not to be published by non-Muslims?

I am interested in two cases:

- generic representation (for instance the one that got López Prater fired recently, a 14th-century image that shows a winged and crowned Angel Gabriel pointing at the Prophet Muhammad and delivering to him the first Quranic revelation)
- caricature

Finally, I assume a country where blasphemy is not a felony (and the legal system is not base on Shariah)

Comment: If I am not wrong the people were attacked for drawing or exhibiting caricatures of the Prophet. The issue is the inherent blasphemy and not just depicting (although depicting is prohibited in Islam as well).

Comment: @UmH: this is a good point, I will cover both points in my question (caricatures and not caricatures)

Comment: And if you are interested in the ruling on (non-blasphemous) images of prophets then this is relevant: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38980/ and for the rulings on images in general see: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/57985/

Comment: @UmH *Does this answer your question?* - partly. I will rephrase to cover both cases